# c# protobuf reflection usage

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

I am using official c# protobuf(not Protobuf-net). Dose it support create a message object according to its type?

The typical deserialize is like：

```
MyProtoMessageClass obj = MyProtoMessageClass.Parser.ParseFrom(byteArray);
```

But how to generate the instance according to a string which is

```
"MyProtoMessageClass"
```

or a obj of `Google.Protobuf.Reflection.MessageDescriptor` which is

```
MyProtoMessageClass.Descriptor
```

?

**UPDATE**

```
delegate void handler(object data);
class Wrapper
{
    public handler h;
    public global::Google.Protobuf.IMessage m;
}
Dictionary<ushort, Wrapper> dict = new Dictionary<ushort, Wrapper>();


// register
class HandlerClass {
    public void handle(object o) {
        ProtoMessageClass data = (ProtoMessageClass)o;
        // use data 
    }
}
h = HandlerClassObj.handle;
m = new ProtoMessageClass();
dict[1] = new Wrapper{h = h, m = m};

// call
ushort cmd = 1;// from socket
byte[] dataRecv; // from socket
var w = dict[cmd];
Google.Protobuf.IMessage msg = w.m.Descriptor.Parser.ParseFrom(dataRecv);
w.h.Invoke(msg);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume we got this proto definition:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package tutorial;
option csharp_namespace = "T1.Models";

message Person {
    int32 id = 1;
    string name = 2;
}
```

Compiling this proto file, we get a class called `Person` that implements `Google.Protobuf.IMessage`.
This interface contains a property `MessageDescriptor Descriptor { get; }`, which is implemented by the class `Person` and returns a public static property of type `MessageDescriptor`.

The `MessageDescriptor` contains a public static property called `Parser`, and we can call the `ParseFrom(byteArray)` of this.

the code:

```
var typ = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().First(t => t.Name == "Person"); //get the type using the string we got, here it is 'Person'
var descriptor = (MessageDescriptor)typ.GetProperty("Descriptor", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null, null); // get the static property Descriptor
var person = descriptor.Parser.ParseFrom(byteArray); // parse the byte array to Person
```

Comment: Thanks, I found this can meet my requirement: Google.Protobuf.IMessage msg = new MyProtoMessageClass();
msg.Descriptor.Parser.ParseFrom(byte); The msg object only used to get the descriptor object and due to all msg type is IMessage so I can put them into an container

Comment: @jean, actually you can have a Dictionary<string,MessageParser>, filled with the static MyProtoMessageClass.Descriptor.Parser, if that's the case let me know so I update the answer to help others. (the descriptor is static, no need to new an instance).

Comment: Yes I have an Dictionary<int, MessageParser>, and when my app recv data from tcp connection, I get a int variable 'cmd' and a byte[] 'data'. I need to create proto message obj according to 'cmd' value to find out which message class obj I need to create and pass data to the creation function. Currently I use Dictionary<int, IMessage>

Comment: Of course when I use the obj, I will downcast it to the right sub type. Doing this can avoid duplicate the parser code

Comment: @jean, can you show the code you use to populate the dict?

Comment: @jean, the `Descriptor.Parser.ParseFrom` always creates a new instance of IMessage,so you are creating an extra instance that's useless. why not adding a property called MessageDescriptor to your wrapper. in that way you can assign ProtoMessageClass.Descriptor to it, without creating an instance.

Comment: Somethings I will use the instance due to some message define only contain an repeated field and the message field size is zero. In this case, I need pass the instance to hander function rather than pass null. And MessageDescriptor.Parser can not parse a empty byte[]

Comment: Thanks for this, is this still the best way forwards as of today?